# How to handle Checkbox in asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form in which a check box with code as below

```
<aspCheckBox ID="txtIsPaid" runat="server" autopostback="true" 
              OnCheckedChanged="txtIsPaid_CheckedChanged" />
```

is used.and in sql database datatype is bit.
 but when i checked or unchecked this box the value is always false in database. i googled but in     vain.

```
protected void txtIsPaid_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtIsPaid.Checked == true)
    {
        EmployeeLeave empleave = new EmployeeLeave();
         empleave.IsPaid = txtIsPaid.Checked;
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some DAL code to share? You need to commit the change to the database.

Comment: Not [tag:asp-classic] you want [tag:asp.net].

Comment: Your also missing a colon (`:`) in `<asp:CheckBox ID="txtIsPaid" runat="server" autopostback="true" 
              OnCheckedChanged="txtIsPaid_CheckedChanged" />` `asp:` is the namespace the control belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to see if the value is even being changed, and take it from there:

```
 bool isitchecked = txtIsPaid.checked;
 Console.WriteLine(isitchecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your `IsPaid` setter already run `UPDATE` SQL?
It seems you don't update to database.

Maybe you must call save function, ex:

```
protected void txtIsPaid_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
  if (txtIsPaid.Checked == true) { 
    EmployeeLeave empleave = new EmployeeLeave();
    empleave.IsPaid = txtIsPaid.Checked;
    empleave.Save();
  }
}
```